# How do I call a webservice over SSL in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I have recently been working on a C# application that calls a webservice over SSL and handles the certificate security using a delegate for the ServerCertificateValidationCallback event like so:

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(object certsender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            bool validationResult = false;

            // if there are no SSL validation errors
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                validationResult = true;
            }

            return validationResult;
        };
```

Now I need to do the same thing in Java and this is where I'm stuck - I've googled for a while and not really found a straight-forward answer. How do I handle SSL certificate validation in Java?

Comment: A glaring omission in my question is that I want to accept self-signed certificates. I have since found the following article that explains how to do this: http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Java/SelfSignedCerts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent java version do it for you.  Just point to an HTTPS URL (https://)

Answer (score 1):

Apache HTTPClient is the best way to handle anything more than a simple get on a URL.  Here is the [SSL Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html).